# Change style of glyphicon on focus of input field

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to change the color of the glyphicon when a user focus on input field. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="form-group inner-addon left-addon">
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user userglyphicon"></i>
 <input class="form-control user"  name="username placeholder="Username">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reversed the position of the `input` and `glyphicon`, so we can access the `glyphicon` as a sibling.

To put the `glyphicon` in front of the `input` field, I defined the `form-group` as a `flexbox` and used `order` to reposition the elements.

```css
.form-group1,
.form-group2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-group1 input,
.form-group2 input {
  order: 2;
}

.form-group1 i,
.form-group2 i {
  order: 1;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

.form-group1 input:focus+i {
  color: red;
}

.form-group2 input:focus+i {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group1 inner-addon left-addon">
  <input class="form-control user" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
  <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group2 inner-addon left-addon">
  <input class="form-control user" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
  <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: They will need a different class name to separate them. Then use those class names in the CSS.

Comment: Code is adjusted for 2 groups. The top icon turns red, the bottom one turns blue.

Comment: Thanks .This is helpful